# Does it make sense to benchmark an existing quantum computer today?

Tags: speedup

Given the fact that, as far as I know, existing quantum technology is not advanced enough to claim any supremacy in any field, does it make sense to benchmark these devices to compare the performances wrt classical hardware ?

My point is that, most (if not all) of the quantum algorithms where it is proved a quantum advantage in terms of time complexity, are designed for hardware that doesn't exist (yet). This makes me think that this kind of benchmarking does not make much sense and this is the reason why I haven't found any paper or work doing it (this is still an assumption of mine).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was one "not very well-known" [study](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-019-1666-5?categoryid=2849273&discountcode=DSI19S?categoryid=2849273) which benchmarked a programmable superconducting processor with the classical supercomputer Summit and a bunch of additional supercomputers at Google. Since then, there have been many other related benchmarks.

Overall, I don't think you looked well. There are hundreds of papers benchmarking quantum hardware with all sorts of classical hardware on different problems.

It is always possible to simulate a quantum device to some extent and then design statistical tests and experiments for benchmarking estimated runtimes of quantum vs classical computation. This kind of stuff is done routinely on daily basis.

Comment: Hello @MonteNero, thanks for your reply. Could you please point me to any of this benchmarking works related to machine learning or optimization, if any comes to your mind ?

Comment: Hi Elle. I'll let Google Scholar to have this honor.

Comment: I was not being "lazy", I was just trying to receive a good suggestion. Thanks anyway =)

Comment: @MarkS will do.